# Is it possible to catch an error exit code in node.js from shell script?

Tags: node.js, bash, shell, sh, exit-code

as the title of the question, here is the scenario.

A shell script file `script.sh` that does some operations and at some point it requires to launch a node file.

```bash
#! /bin/bash

node "$(dirname "$0")/script.js" "$input"

echo "${?}\n"
```

In the node file `script.js` there are some controls and in case of error the script return with an error exit code.

```js
process.exit(1)
```

Is it possible to catch this error exit code in order to let the command to be executed in the shell script `script.sh`?

Currently the execution is interrupted with this error `error Command failed with exit code 1.`, as expected by the way.
But I would like to know if I can on shell script to catch this error and continue to execute the last part of the code `echo "${?}\n"`.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What was the value of `echo "${?}"` printed?

Comment: As I said, the execution is interrupted so nothing happens in `script.sh` after calling `node "$(dirname "$0")/script.js" "$input"
`. But I would expect `echo` to print 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this in your bash script in case your node script return 1

```
node "$(dirname "$0")/script.js" "$input"
   echo "Script: $? - Successfull"
if [ $? != 0 ]; then                   
   echo "${?}\n". 1>&2 && exit 1
fi
```

Comment: I've just on my standard output this error => `error Command failed with exit code 1.` and anything else happens in the `script.sh` after calling `node "$(dirname "$0")/script.js" "$input"`.

Comment: ah, it is because of `set -o errexit` coming from another shell script that actually calls mine.